# On Linux Mint 17.x, how do I find out what version of Qt is used?

Tags: linux, qt, version, linux-mint

I'm pretty new to Linux and am maintaining an application that runs on Mint 17.x.  The application has a bug that seems to be related to an old version of Qt 5.

How can I find out what version of Qt 5 is on a freshly-created Mint 17.x machine?

Comment: A search brings up a ton of results. Did you forget to search first or did none of them work for you? Specifically `qmake -v`?

Comment: yes, I searched, sorry should have mentioned:  qmake -v gives me "qmake:  could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory."  I'm not interested in qt4 - I need the qt5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Qt 5 on Mint distros, as you can see [here](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint)

Comment: Good to know where to look!  I'm really surprised - I thought all linux distros by now shipped with both a qt4 and a qt5 version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Mint, but what I tried on Debian Jessie is first looking for the qt directory via

`ls /usr/share/ | grep qt`

I then changed to the directory /usr/share/qt5. From there, I did

`grep -r "QtCore 5"`

I found a match in /usr/share/qt5/doc/qtcore.qch/

Opening up the file in vim (or whichever editor you prefer), I searched for "QtCore 5" to find the major version. I found several mentions of QtCore 5.3 but none of "QtCore 5.1", "QtCore 5.2", or "QtCore 5.4". To find the minor version, I searched for variants of "project.qtcore.53X" where X is the minor version number. I found "project.qtcore.532" but not any other variant.

Note that for vim searches you will have to use a "\" character to escape the "." regex.

Comment: doing the first step demonstrated that there is no qt5 on Mint.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QtCreator:

`Tools > Options... > Build & Run > Qt Versions`